# Startup with no devops experience, having scaling issues

Tags: lamp

hopefully I can get some help here, even though I have a pretty vague issue.

We created a startup that is starting to get quite a bit of traffic. We set up a load balancer to 2 pretty large servers. One server handles our database, but it load balances between the 2 servers. LAMP stack.

However, it seems that we're having constant scaling issues. Now we're not very familiar with devops and our hosting bill is already quite large. Not sure where to go from here to solve our issues. We use a managed server service.

1 - Do we hire a devops guy to look into our problem? If so, where's the best place to look?

2 - What else can we do? We have very little knowledge of devops (created by coders) so it's a bit difficult to know how to even get started with this.

Comment: "We're a company doing some stuff that I won't specify and we're having some problems with some technology that I won't specify or provide any detailed information about. Can you help us?" - No, Kevin. We cannot help you. If they gave awards for being vague you would win the top prize!

Comment: `We created a startup that is starting to scale.` - What does that mean? What are you scaling? Be specific. `We set up a load balancer to 2 pretty large servers` - Load balancing what? Large servers? What kind of servers? Web servers? Database servers? What? `However, it seems that we're having constant scaling issues.` Again, scaling what exactly? `What else can we do?` - You could start by giving us some information that's actually useful so that maybe we can help you.

Comment: "Not sure where to go from here to solve our issues." - HIRE SOMEONE WHO KNOWS. SImple like that. THere are people that have many years of experience in exactly this. And if they get stuck, they know enough to actually analyze the problem and - ask for help giving SPECIFIC details. Yes, you have to pay them. That is what people expect for years of experience.

Comment: Whow, firs time i do not know which topic to choose. Learning material? Best business practices? Asking or a service recommendtation.

Comment: Problem is, we really don't know what the issue is, but like you guys said, we'll go ahead and just hire someone to look into it.

Comment: @kevinkt The problem is, you haven't told us anything from which we could even begin to guess what your problems and challenges are. Your question is devoid of any detail from which we could even attempt to provide an answer. How are you going to present this to someone who you may want to hire? `We have a thing but sometimes it doesn't work. Can you help us make it work?` - How do you plan to describe your problem and your needs in order to attract the right candidates? Your question is so vague as to make your problem completely indiscernible.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we hire a devops guy to look into our problem? If so, where's the best place to look?

No, [DevOps](https://newrelic.com/devops/what-is-devops) isn't a job, it's a way of working. You need to hire someone who is competent in system administration. He can use DevOps techniques, or he may not, 2 servers isn't that big of a set up. DevOps isn't only about System Administration anyway, as the name imply.

> What else can we do? We have very little knowledge of devops (created by coders) so it's a bit difficult to know how to even get started with this.

The right way to get a system that has some value up and running and keeping it running is to have a person who has been trained and ideally has experience in the subject of system administration.

In your case, it would be Web System Administration, and LAMP stack. Ideally, the person is familiar also with the cloud hosting company you are using.

Ideal, the person has training and hopefully experience in Site Reliability Engineering, or whatever other titles have been given to that type of function. That will get you further.

But you can start with someone with good training/background in web system administration.

There is no way around it, if you want a professional set up.